# Configure X11R6 source cross-compilation for ARM

Tags: linux, arm, x11

I am trying to cross build X11R6.6 for ARM architecture.
I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS as the build system. And yes, I **do** understand X11R6 is pretty much outdated, but its a client requirement.

The target/host is (uname -a) :

```
    Linux freescale 2.6.31-207-g7286c01 #1617 PREEMPT Wed Aug 7 10:45:59 IST 2013 armv5tejl GNU/Linux
```

The toolchain used :

```
    arm-none-linux-gnueabi-4.1.2 glibc-2.5 nptl-3
```

The problem is that after **make install** I can't find any server binaries (X, Xorg, XFree86, Xfbdev, etc.) in the install binaries directory, although there are other binaries getting built & installed (xinit, xclock, twm, xconsole, etc.). Checked the source after build, these server binaries are not getting built.

I am pretty sure it must be something to do with the source configuration (X11R6 build system is a headache...apparently).

The build system consists of different **.cf** & **.def** files (site.def, host.def, linux.cf, xf86site.def, etc.) , which we have to edit according to our configuration. I do have a general idea about these, But I have not completely understood all details of it. I ahve enabled **Serverbuild** options wherever applicable. I have also googled a lot...but haven't found anything solid yet.

So is there any resource/sample tutorial/blog which can guide me as how exactly to configure X11R6 ? Or if anyone has built X11R6 for ARM, or has any suggestions...kindly oblige...thanks.

EDIT:

Very sorry, forgot to mention an important point. The sources wer downloaded through LTIB (Linux Target Image Builder) tool for Freescale. The package name is XFree86-4.4.0. Links follow :

http://bitshrine.org/gpp//XFree86-4.4.0-src-1.tgz
http://bitshrine.org/gpp//XFree86-4.4.0-src-2.tgz
http://bitshrine.org/gpp//XFree86-4.4.0-src-3.tgz
http://bitshrine.org/gpp//XFree86-4.4.0-src-4.tgz
http://bitshrine.org/gpp//XFree86-4.4.0-src-5.tgz
http://bitshrine.org/gpp//XFree86-4.4.0-src-6.tgz
http://bitshrine.org/gpp//XFree86-4.4.0-src-7.tgz

EDIT  :
LTIB version is 9.1.1 (i think so because ltib script has "App version : 9.1.1"), and it was given by Freescale.
Output of the  `./ltib -m listpkgs | grep xorg` 
 `xorg-server-1.6.1-2 --------- xorg-server ----------- y -- X11 -- X.Org server`

Comment: Have R6 ever worked on arm with your graphics adapter?.. Anyway, please give a link to exact source code - it's not a theoretical question.

Comment: very sorry....forgot to mention an important point. I have edited the question.

Comment: Please supply the output of `./ltib -m listpkgs | grep xorg`.  Also, there is a *Savannah* project and some hosted by *Freescale*; which exact version?  In mine, I have the package *xorg-server*, it should have a 'Y' in the list above; lets make sure you have that.  See: [Savannah's xorg-server spec file](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/ltib/dist/lfs-5.1/xorg-server/?root=ltib)

Comment: I have added the details to the question. Basically I build & deploy single pkgs in the rootfs. The one listed above is xorg-server-1.6.1. But I am trying to build XFree86 (4.4) as mentioned above.